# preg_replace not working?

Tags: php, whitespace

Okay,

So here is my code:

```
        $explode = explode("+ ", $article);
        $explode_count = count($explode);

        for($i=0;$i<$explode_count;$i++)
        {
            $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $explode[$i]);
            $letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', ' ', $explode[$i]);  

            if($letters == "All Star Game")
            {
                 echo "Done";
            } 
        }
```

The $letters variable is equal to All Star Game. But, for some reason, "Done" isn't being echoed. Could it be something with the preg_replace function that I'm using to separate the numbers from the letters in the string? I notice that when I change the $letters variable to

```
   $letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $explode[$i]);
```

and set the rest of the code to:

```
if($letters == "AllStarGame")
{
     echo "Done";
}
```

Then, php echoes it out. What's going on in regards to spaces here?

Comment: what does `$letters` have in it?

Comment: Well, in this case, it has "All Star Game"

Comment: Nevermind `$letters`, it's more crucial what's in `$article`. Why are there plus signs? Why do you expect the spaces to remain, when the regex excludes them? Also, why not use a `foreach`?

Comment: In my case, $article is equal to "Array + Jake Arrieta + Tommy Hunter + 1933 All Star Game + Jason Heyward 1903 World Series + 2012 New York Yankees + "

Comment: You can use `foreach()` instead of `for()` loop.

Comment: Would using a foreach() instead of a for() loop solve my problem though? sometimes, there might be the same value twice in the string that gets exploded (and hence turned into an array), so i figured that it would be better to use a for() loop.

Comment: @Lance: `for ()` will not protect you against this same value twice. For that use `array_unique()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an input with `+ 1933 All Star Game +` then your regex will convert the text snippet into something like `␣␣␣␣␣␣All␣Star␣Game␣`. (The `␣` represents a space).

That's because you `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', ' ')` any non-letter with a space there. So the `1933` will become four spaces, the two surrounding spaces will remain. Which is why your final comparison of `$letters == "All Star Game"` will never match.

Comment: As an aside, you can use `trim` to get rid of the leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! My absent mindedness has caused me great confusions at times. But, I had a feeling that it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your regexp excludes spaces.

```
$letters = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', ' ', $explode[$i]);
//                          ^ I only accept letters, not spaces
```

The solution be to forget regexp and explode by `' + '`.

```
<?php
$teams = explode(' + ', $article);

foreach ($teams as $team) {
    if ($team == "All Star Game") {
         echo "Done";
    } 
}
```

Be warned that you may have trailling empty string at end of the array (your string contains `' + '` at end, but you can easily `break` when seeing empty string.

Comment: How can I make it so that my regexp includes spaces? It's important that I separate numbers from letters in my situation.

Comment: @Lance, add space. `[^a-zA-Z ]`

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep that in mind. to be honest, I'm not too familiar with regular expressions.